# Symfony how to insert into a form a type Array | IteratorAggregate?

Tags: forms, symfony, orm

In symfony I have a `ManyToOne` relation :

```
Each Article has One Category.
Each Category may have Many Article.
```

Here are my two entities :

**Article**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
private $content;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $createdAt;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $image;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $editedAt;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category")
 */
private $category;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getTitle(): ?string
{
    return $this->title;
}

public function setTitle(string $title): self
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}

public function getContent(): ?string
{
    return $this->content;
}

public function setContent(string $content): self
{
    $this->content = $content;

    return $this;
}

public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
{
    return $this->createdAt;
}

public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self
{
    $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

    return $this;
}

public function getImage(): ?string
{
    return $this->image;
}

public function setImage(?string $image): self
{
    $this->image = $image;

    return $this;
}

public function getEditedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
{
    return $this->editedAt;
}

public function setEditedAt(?\DateTimeInterface $editedAt): self
{
    $this->editedAt = $editedAt;

    return $this;
}

public function getCategory(): ?Category
{
    return $this->category;
}

public function setCategory(?Category $category): self
{
    $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
}
```

**Category**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\Unique(message="Cette catégorie existe déjà")
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * @param $name
 * @return mixed
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    return $this->name = $name;
}
```

I have a basic form to add new category :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class)
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
            'label' => 'Add a new category'
        ])
    ;
}
```

The controller that handle the request :

```
public function addCategory(Request $request)
{
    $category = new Category();
    $form = $this->createForm(CategoryType::class, $category);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $category->setName($request->request->get('category_add')['name']);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($category);
        $em->flush();
    }
    return $this->render('admin/category.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

The problem is that when I try to submit the form with any value in the `Name` input it returns : `This value should be of type array|IteratorAggregate.`

Comment: erase this line:         $category->setName($request->request->get('category_add')['name']);
and see what happens. I bet you will be surprised (check your DB after)

Comment: Not related to the question but your Assert\Unique is not what you are looking for to ensure that the name is not present in the DB yet. Have a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html instead

Comment: Try to set the data_class in your form and instead of creating the Category yourself just do  $category = $form->getData() in the if statement.
Is there a relation back to Article from category ?

Comment: But your error is caused by the Unique Assert. From the documentation : This constraint can be applied to any property of type array or \Traversable. It is not suited for a string field and is only applied if the value is not null

Comment: @craigh I erased the line and recreated the database, I still have the same issue it has something to do with the `&& $form->isValid()`

Comment: @FlorianHermann thanks ! i'll read it

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\Unique(message="Cette catégorie existe déjà")
 */
private $name;
```

with

```
/**
* @UniqueEntity("name")
/
class Category{

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;
```

The Unique Assert : This constraint can be applied to any property of type array or \Traversable.

Edit: Forgot to remove the Assert\Unique

Comment: This is not related to the question as a mentionned in the comments

Comment: Yes You are right! My bad. That's true because the name is concidered as an array because of this!

Comment: Yes, its this line : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/c6cf433589ead18e8390ecaa1fa4915ff553843e/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/UniqueValidator.php#L37

Comment: thanks a lot guys ! you really helped me from turning crazy